# Python Function Takes too Long as Dictionary Gets too Big

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

```
def assign_ID(dic,id):
  for key, value in enumerate(dic):
    for elem in range(value):
      if id in dic[value]:
        return value
```

My function above does what I want it to do-- but the problem is that as the dictionary dic gets bigger in the main part of my program, my "assign_ID" function takes too long.  Initially this function takes about 1/100 of a second to run, but after a few thousand rows of input, it starts to take half a second, then a full second and then longer.  The trouble is that my input file is so large that ultimately this function makes the whole program take at least two full days to run.

Is there a way to re-write the above function so that it runs quicker?  I would like to be able to periodically run this program so I really want it to run faster than it does.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't think `enumerate(dic)` does what you think it does.  Can you describe your data structure and the task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, so "dic" is a defaultdict(http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html).  My goal is to see whether the id in question has previously been assigned to a key previously.  We kept having issues with various sorts causing different id's, so I wanted to be thorough and check through the whole dictionary to see if the value occurred elsewhere.  Is this the way you would think about it?

Comment: What are the values of the defaultdict? If they are lists, and the lists become big then every `in` operator will take a lot of time. You should consider using `set`s instead.

Comment: Uh... you have an O(n) step with `for elem in range(value)` that does literally nothing.

Comment: What are you doing? `assign_ID` doesn't appear to do that... Rather returns the key if the key is in the `dict`? So your above at a cursory glance just looks like a convoluted way of writing `id in dic`...

Comment: @Bakuriu, the values of the defaultdict are lists.

Comment: @JonClements, assign_ID returns the key and then the main program stores the key as the new_id

Comment: @JonClements No. It checks whether `id` is in a *value*, not if it is a key of the dictionary.

Comment: If you want the value to appear only once in the whole dataset, then a dictionary of lists is the wrong datastructure.

Comment: @Bakuriu right you are - I was trying to force myself to read `value` as key, and brain didn't want to switch back after ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, straight off the bat, get rid of `enumerate`.  Also, your second for-loop does nothing.  Get rid of that too:

```
def assign_ID(dic, id):
    for key in dic:
        if id in dic[key]:
            return key
```

The above function should do everything that your old one does, only it will be far faster.

Comment: @delnan - Good call.  I just copy/pasted his code so I didn't really notice that.

Comment: Oh, now I noticed another simplification, the key is never used so we could just use `dic.values()`. (Edit: nonsense, see below.)

Comment: @delnan: Well, the key is returned. Although it's unclear if that's needed.

Comment: This will have quadratic performance due to the implied loop in the in-statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `iteritems` to iterate over the dictionary items more efficiently (in Python 2.x):

```
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    if id in v:
        return k
```

as observed by @Bakuriu, in Python 3.x:

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    if id in v:
        return k
```

since in Python 3.x `items()` will give an iterator, similarly to `iteritems()` in Python 2.x.

Comment: Note that `iteritems()` was removed in python3. Use `items()` instead(which works also in python2, even though with slightly different semantics).